# Fill corners with faces on an adaptable mesh tool with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Still quite new to Geometry Nodes and having trouble achieving my goal.
I'm trying to adapt the code of another blender user to build a little precedural architectural tool:
[image]

Every side of the main-mesh-plane has an element with a fixed width (in the example image 6m) and the rest is averaged at the ends (x). This x is changing everytime on every side differently, depending on the side-length of the main-mesh-plane and the size of the elements.

I managed to extrude the main facade elements, but not the corners, where I need not only the edges but also faces to apply geometry to them with the tissue addon.

[image: end result with many floors (having the corner bug)]
[image: one floor. picture of the blender file attached (having the corner-bug)]

I appreciate your suggestions and ideas. Thank you for your precious time!

Comment: This could be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298140/how-can-i-instantiate-objects-along-an-edge-without-gaps-and-fix-the-normals/

Comment: i'll take a closer look for sure! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already written in the other answer:
*There is hardly any useful way to get a satisfactory result only from vertical edges, so it is easier to process the horizontal edges.*

That's why I'm using a combination of the following two answers here:

- [Fill corners with faces only having vertical edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/306468/145249)
- [How can I instantiate objects along an edge without gaps and fix the normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298193/145249)

The setup then looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The difference to the existing answers is that no instances are used here for the facade elements, but only extruded edges.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.5.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Awsome! working perfectly! im gonna study the setup... thanks a lot for the incredible help!